# children doesn't stretch on height using flexbox

Tags: html, flexbox

Im trying to use flexbox on my page. Im bumping on a very easy (I guess) problem. I started with a header footer and 3 sections. The header and footers needs to be 100% width and height depends on text in the header and footer itself.

The section on the other hand needs to be the remaining 100% height and width but this is not the problem. I fixed this with flex: 1 0px;

I uploaded my code to [Fiddle have a look](https://jsfiddle.net/f7mhd8uc/1/).

```
 section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-self: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
  }
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}


/* MEDIA QUERYS */


/*
  ## Desktops
  ## Schermgrootte = 1281px of hoger
*/

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #container>* {
    flex: 1 100%;
  }
  section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-self: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
  }
  header {
    align-self: flex-start;
    background: green;
  }
  footer {
    align-self: flex-start;
    background: gray;
  }
  #informatie {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    flex: 1 0px;
  }
  #omgeving {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    flex: 1 0px;
  }
  #voorraden {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: 1 0px;
  }
}


/*
  ## Laptops
  ## Schermgrootte = 961px tot 1280px
*/

@media (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  #informatie {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
  #omgeving {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
  #voorraden {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}


/*
  ## Telefoons
  ## Schermgrootte = 320px tot 960px
*/

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 960px) {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Samir Alieev - Challenge 1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <section id="container">
    <header>
      Welkom op de dashboard van de ruimteschip ITS. Hierin kunt u alle benodigde informatie vinden wat betreft de ruimteschip en het reis naar Mars. Een fijne reis toegewenst!
    </header>
    <section id="informatie">
      Voertuig informatie
    </section>
    <section id="omgeving">
      Voertuig omgeving
    </section>
    <section id="voorraden">
      Voorraden
    </section>
    <footer>
      Footer
    </footer>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to add 100% height to my container, everything gets this property. I deleted this property from the footer and header but as you can tell there is a huge gap between the section and header. There is also a huge gap between the footer and end of the page.

I also tried adding this code to the sections but it did not work out. What do I miss here?

Since it's unclear to some of you, here is a preview what I am trying to achieve [image]

Comment: Unclear to me here, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited my question with a preview what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to wrap your sections in another element, but once you've done that it's pretty easy to do:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

main section {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}

/* Just colours below here */

header {
  background: green;
}

#informatie {
  background: red;
}

#omgeving {
  background: blue;
}

#voorraden {
  background: teal;
}

footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<article id="container">
  <header>
    Welkom op de dashboard van de ruimteschip ITS. Hierin kunt u alle benodigde informatie vinden wat betreft de ruimteschip en het reis naar Mars. Een fijne reis toegewenst!
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="informatie">
      Voertuig informatie
    </section>
    <section id="omgeving">
      Voertuig omgeving
    </section>
    <section id="voorraden">
      Voorraden
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</article>
```

Just set the parent container to column format with the "main" to flex grow, and then set the sections within that to "flex: 1 0 0px" to give them even width

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve indeed but I still have 1 problem. I get a scrollbar right to the browser. I don't want this, I want it to be the full page not longer than that, do I have to add max-height?

Comment: @Blank Then I guess you have something extra that isn't in my example causing that. How big is the scroll bar? I'm guessing it may be caused by margin and/or padding on an element that's part of the 100% height tree.

Answer (score 0):

You need set the style section that take all page and you need set style footer that is on bottom page. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/a9gs8r4v/)

```
#idcontainer{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    WIDTH: 100%;
    HEIGHT: 100%;
}
footer{
position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: is it really necessarily to use position in this case? I thought there were other solutions just with flexbox

Comment: you should consider also if the site should work in all version site...if you use IE9 the css not work

Comment: There is still this huge gap between header and the sections

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani Anything IE10 and below isn't supported by Microsoft anymore. Neither should we.

Answer (score 0):

First I created a div with the class flexcontainer. Then I gave the items flex: 1

```
<body>
    <header>

    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="flexcontainer">
            <div>flex item 1</div>
            <div>flex item 2</div>
            <div>flex item 3</div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.flexcontainer{
    display: flex;
}

.flexcontainer div{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em;
}
```